# How to use Prism plugins with Docusaurus v2?

Tags: reactjs, syntax-highlighting, docusaurus, prismjs

I would like to use [diff-highlighting](https://prismjs.com/plugins/diff-highlight/) on my documentation – which requires installing a plugin

It is apparently not installed by default, but there is no documentation on how to add plugins (only languages, which doesn't work for plugins)

How can I install prisms plugins in Docusaurus v2?

Comment: Do you have the plugin you would like to install, or is that part of the question?

Comment: The plugin is linked in the question: https://prismjs.com/plugins/diff-highlight/

Comment: for some reason I am unable to open the link from my mobile. Is there a packaged `json` for prism?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/ngx-prism/core#installation) what you need?

Comment: I am using docusaurus, a React app. The answer has to be compatible with prism-React-renderer and docusaurus

Comment: Did you not install docusauras using `npm`? it is essentially a `npm` component.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what your argument is though.

Comment: my argument is. if you install prismjs via `npm` you can add the plugin to your docusaurus configuration.

Comment: prismjs is already installed via npm when using docusaurus, as a peer dependency.

Comment: So then just configure your docusarus config to include prism to it.. will see if I can find a link quick.

Comment: [this](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/using-plugins/) should help?

Comment: Prism is already included. That's not the problem. It's about how to make Docusaurus use Prism plugins. As for the link you gave, this is a different kind of plugins – it is docusaurus plugins not prism plugins

Comment: The closest would be to use the `swizzle` feature of Docusaurus to extract the theme/Highlight component and modify the code using prism-react-renderer. But I wasn't successful with that

Comment: This seems to still be accurate in 2023

Answer (score 0):

It works out of the box

````
```
diff
+ hey
- ho
    
hello
```
````

[image]

Comment: This question is not about `diff` but rather a variant that has both the diff highlight and the syntax highlight of your programing language. So for Dart, it would be `diff-dart`

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way seems to be using `swizzle` on `prism-include-languages`, which is a pretty elegant solution.

This process is [documented](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/code-blocks#supported-languages) by Docusaurus.

Here is the relevant [feature request](https://docusaurus.io/feature-requests/p/include-prism-diff-highlight).